# write an array of objects directly on pug

Tags: pug

I would like to know if I can write an object on pug, this code is working but I think I would be better if I can write the object directly.

```
mixin about(title, paragraphe)
  - var columns_content = []
  - columns_content.push({title:'Brand',paragraphe:'hola'})
  - columns_content.push({title:'Digital',paragraphe:'hola'})
  - columns_content.push({title:'Print',paragraphe:'hola'})
```

Comment: I don't get what your trying to accomplish. Do you mean write an object without pushing?

Comment: yes, i want to write the object without pushing

Comment: Why are you trying to write an object in the template instead of in your route?  This is a trivial exercise in the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol - allows you to use native javascript. So you can do this.

```
- var columns_content = [
-  {title:'Brand',paragraphe:'hola'},
-  {title:'Digital',paragraphe:'hola'},
-  {title: 'Print',paragraphe:'hola'}
-  ]
```

**Or**

```
- var columns_content = [  {title:'Brand',paragraphe:'hola'},{title:'Digital',paragraphe:'hola'},  {title: 'Print',paragraphe:'hola'} ]
```